# Why does screen recording get error when i screen recording with command line

Tags: android, adb, screen-recording

I am trying to do a screen recording of my Android device by following [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording) article but I get the following error:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
/system/bin/sh: screenrecord: not found
```

My Android device is running version 4.1.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the article you linked:

> Android 4.4 adds support for screen recording and provides a screen
>   recording utility that lets you start and stop recording on a device
>   that's connected to your Android SDK environment over USB.

Now, Android 4.1.2 is not 4.4, so that's why the required binary is not found on the device.

Comment: Can I copy the binary from an Android 4.4 device?

Comment: @JohnyTex IDK. If copying does not work, you could try to build it from source. You will need root for placing it on the device however.

Comment: Yeah I realized it wasn't compiled for arm, so then as you say, you need to build it yourself. Thx though.

Answer (score 0):

the article you linked is about the new APIs include from Android KitKat 4.4.
if your device runs a lower version of Android, you cant run these new features.