# How to record screen in android from inside or outside the app?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, screen-capture, screencast

I see some apps on Google Play which allow you to record entire screen for Android version 5.0+ I have been digging into android reference for a while but could not figure our a right way to do it. Could someone please provide me just a small hint ?

Also, I understand Android system won't give you full screen buffer access for version < 5.0+, However is there any way to just record my own app's screen cast within the app ? One approach I came up with is to take snapshot of the screen few times every second and put them in encoder to create a video, however, this looks like a very heavy approach. Can anybody please suggest a better way to do it ?

Comment: Do you need it as a feature in the app or just want to record for purpose of making a video of the app a single time?

Comment: @Msk - Yes, I would like to incorporate it as a feature so that app users can record their session and upload it on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source1](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-screen-on-android-4-4-kitkat/) and [Source2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21367368)

For Android 4.4+ you can record using command line 
`adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4`

**EDIT**
If you want it as a feature of your app, so that user can record their screen. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25300536) It has a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how can I do it from inside the app ? It's a shell command, can I invoke it from java ?

Comment: Hey @Sai , Your edited answer was helpful. Do you think taking 16 screenshots per second ( 16 fps ) will be a good idea ?

Comment: @AmitGupta If i were you, I would check myself

Comment: @AmitGupta have you checked with 16fps..? If it is helpful mark it as an answer